# Three Js - Database for 3D Model

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

Good day, everyone.
Currently, I am working on a website implemented with Three.js. I am interested in any suitable platform or online database to store the 3D model file and the website database together if possible.

I would be very appreciative of that!

Currently, I am using local storage for the website and I am hosting it on `www.000webhost.com` but I found that the web host does not provide an option or way to upload the model directly from my website.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for services to host your `three.js` website, that will allow you to also host the 3D models served in your website. You can try `https://vercel.com/`, amazon web services, `https://render.com`, etc. They also have instructions on how to serve your app.